# Best approach to retaining cachability of images served by ImageResizer from S3?

Tags: imageresizer

We've been evaluating ImageResizer as a tool to dynamically resize and optimize images stored in S3 (and remotely) to our app. We've taken pains to make sure that the S3 files are rarely modified once stored, and they have pretty aggressive cache settings.

If we're serving the files straight from S3, that's great: once the app has an image, it knows it's cachable practically forever. But once the image passes through ImageResizer, that information is lost.

It seems to me that there are two parts to this problem:

1. First, that the app knows that the image isn't going to change. I'd like to be able to pass through the original `Cache-Control` header, and probably the original file's `Last-Modified` date, as well.
2. If it has `Last-Modified` and/or `Etag` values for the images, the app will probably attempt conditional GETs at some point. While the server may or may not have a copy of the image still in *its* cache, it would need to be able to associate those original values with that cache entry to respond appropriately.

Is this something that can be accomplished with the stock `S3Reader2` and `DiskCache` (and friends)? If we were to fork `S3Reader2`, is there a defined mechanism for plugins to add headers to the response?

Answer (score 0):

The stock version of S3Reader2 can be configured in two modes: Cache forever, and cache metadata for a sliding or fixed window. If the metadata expires, it checks  S3 for updates.

Last-modified and Etag are provided when DiskCache is installed. Passing those values through would cause issues if you ever wanted to do URL rewriting or enable/disable plugins, as it would be impossible to invalidate files with the client. We mistakenly had this behavior in V2.

Cache-control information is not passed through to the client; that is handled separately, either via the ClientCache or via IIS/web.config rules. Or via the CDN. Typically developers want to control each stage of caching separately - blob to server, server to CDN, CDN to client.

That said, passing a cache-control and/or expires header through is certainly possible if you're willing to modify code. It's not, however, possible to do so if you're caching to disk, as the only metadata preserved on disk is the modified/created/access dates.

Comment: Controlling the behavior at each stage is fine. But it only appears to be possible to apply settings (DiskCache, ClientCache) across _all_ images. What we'd like to be able to do is to take make stronger guarantees for this particular subset of images where we can, and default to weaker ones where we can't.

Comment: You should probably use IIS configuration rules or [roll your own plugin for setting headers - ClientCache itself is only 8 lines (excluding boilerplate)](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/develop/Core/Plugins/Basic/ClientCache.cs)